# Why NSStatusBar's text appears and disappears instantly at app start in Yosemite 10.10?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-yosemite, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

Here is a code how I add a status bar with text:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
    _statusBarItem = [bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [_statusBarItem setTitle:@"Status"];
    [_statusBarItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    [_statusBarItem setMenu:_menu];
}
```

It appears and disappears immediately after I launch my app.
How to fix that?

I use Xcode 6.0 and Yosemite 10.10

I used an example of creating status bar from:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/Tasks/creatingitems.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSStatusItem appears briefly on launch, but promptly disappears](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873418/nsstatusitem-appears-briefly-on-launch-but-promptly-disappears)

Comment: Solved by changing property from weak to strong for _statusBarItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing property from weak to strong for _statusBarItem